Error in IdentityUserAccessor add Scoped Blazor C#
Error in program.cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityUserAccessor>();

System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Blazorteste.Modelo.IdentityUserAccessor Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Blazorteste.Modelo.IdentityUserAccessor': Unable to resolve service for type 'Blazorteste.Modelo.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`6

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Blazorteste.Modelo;

internal sealed class IdentityUserAccessor(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IdentityRedirectManager redirectManager)
{
    public async Task<ApplicationUser> GetRequiredUserAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(context.User);

        if (user is null)
        {
            redirectManager.RedirectToWithStatus("Account/InvalidUser", $"Error: Unable to load user with ID '{userManager.GetUserId(context.User)}'.", context);
        }

        return user;
    }
}

My class ApplicationDbContext.cs
namespace HoteldosNobresBlazor.Modelo;

public class ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>(options)
{
}

I have an error when creating a user to log into Blazor.

Hi, did you add your context to services ("Blazorteste.Modelo.ApplicationDbContext") ?

You also need to add 'services.AddTransient<UserManager>()' in your program.cs
